# Using Enum and want to access the stored integer value in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm using ActiveRecord's [Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to store the weekdays with the following:

```
enum weekday: %w(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday)
```

When calling the attribute `.weekday` on the model instance I correctly get the weekday name, e.g. "monday".

**How could I get the numeric value (i.e. `0`) when I need that instead?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `my_object[:weekday]`, or, if you're in the object, just `self[:weekday]`.

UPDATE:
OR (as found by Ms Numbers): `.read_attribute_before_type_cast(:weekday)`

Comment: This worked though: `.read_attribute_before_type_cast("weekday")`

Comment: Oh interesting, that's a new one for me. Try also my updated answer... it's a bit shorter.

Answer (score 3):

What you would rather want to do is this:

```
model_instance.read_attribute(:weekday)
```

Cleaner, simpler, straight to the point.